# Change the background color of the dragged list in Rubaxa sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rubaxa-sortable

I'm using [Rubaxa sortable](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable) to make a list items sortable. Now i want to change the background color of the list being dragged. 
For now i'm using the ghost class available in the documentation but in that only the text background is colored but i want the whole list along with the numbering to have a background-color. 
can anyone know how can i add a custom classes to the sortable through javascript so that i can achieve the same.

```js
  Sortable.create(simpleList, {
    ghostClass: "ghost"
  });
```

```css
.ghost {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c00;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
ol {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ol id="simpleList" class="list-group">
    <li>A Good Meal</li>
    <li>A technical Improvement</li>
    <li>Nonsense</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: if my understanding is correct give a 100% width for .list-group

Comment: You want entire `ul` to have the same color? or Just that particular `li` which is being dragged? Because, as you can see that particular `li` looses its numbering when it's being dragged. So please clarify your question

Comment: li wont loose its numbering if the list is having 100% width. just check the snippet below

Comment: @TheDarkKnight i want the li along with the numbering to have background color of red.

Comment: Check out @alireza's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I did. Please check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/x0trm6t9/3/). I did some changes in your `html`, `css` and `Jquery`.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <ol id="simpleList" class="list-group">
        <li><span class="index">1.</span>A Good Meal</li>
        <li><span class="index">2.</span>A technical Improvement</li>
        <li><span class="index">3.</span>Nonsense</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ghost {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #c00;
    position: relative;
}
.index {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
ol {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Jquery

```
 Sortable.create(simpleList, {
     ghostClass: "ghost",
     onEnd: function ( /**Event*/ evt) {
         $('.list-group li').each(function (index) {
             var newIndex = index + 1 + '.';
             $(this).find('.index').html(newIndex);
         });
     }
 });
```

Comment: @TheDarkKnight ha ha ha. tnx

Comment: @alirezasafian Thanks a ton. Not only you solved my current problem but this also solved another problem i could have faced. I loved it. It would be helpful if you could post your code here on stack-overflow so that in case the jsfiddle link get broken people can find the code here as well. Please add your code here in the snippet. T

Answer (score 2):

```js
Sortable.create(simpleList, {
    ghostClass: "ghost"
  });
```

```css
.ghost {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c00;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
ol {
  display: inline-block;
}

.list-group{width:100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ol id="simpleList" class="list-group">
    <li>A Good Meal</li>
    <li>A technical Improvement</li>
    <li>Nonsense</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what he asked. He asked the list's numbers to have the same background color

Comment: if the list's numbers have the same background color means it wont be visible.

Comment: What do you mean by "it wont be visible?"

Comment: are you talking about the list-style number?

Comment: Yes... They should have the same background color as the list's `li`

Comment: @TheDarkKnight right. i want the list numbers to have background color of red, along with the list.